# str_replace php a string

Tags: php, str-replace

I have a string

> X_HD003_0

I have a function PHP

```
str_replace()
```

Ugh......

My result that i want:

> HD003

^^, some funny from PPAP song, but some string is: X_HD01_1, X_HD0003_2, X_HD12/12/2016/1_01, this string create by:

> "X_" + String + "_Number"

I want to replace X_ and _Number with str_replace(). Hope everyone can help me! Thank you so much!

Comment: You need to use regular expression for that: `preg_match('/^X_(.*)_\d$/', str)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$parts=explode('_','X_HD003_0');
echo $parts[1];                        //HD003
```

Or in newer versions

```
echo explode('_','X_HD003_0')[1];
```

That should work just fine for all the use cases you mentioned

Comment: Yes, it realy work, thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Try this,

```
function extract_unit($string, $start, $end)
{
    $pos = stripos($string, $start);     
    $str = substr($string, $pos);     
    $str_two = substr($str, strlen($start));     
    $second_pos = stripos($str_two, $end);     
    $str_three = substr($str_two, 0, $second_pos);     
    $unit = trim($str_three); // remove whitespaces     
    return $unit;
}

 $str = "X_HD01_1";     
 $unit = extract_unit($str, '_', '_');

 // Outputs: HD01
 echo $unit;
```

**[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/e6DjZ)**

Comment: Any reason for the Downvote please?

Comment: I don't downvote and i receive a downvote, -_-

Comment: I'm not the author of the downvotes, but I guess the question got it because is terribly written (i can't even understand what it's asking for), while the answer because is missing the use of `str_replace` that the OP explicitly requested: I know sounds finicky, but...hey, it's a programmers website!